# different results in sql

Tags: sql

I have two queries:

1)

```
SELECT a.n
FROM account a, contract c
WHERE c.n = a.r$contract
AND c.n IN (
    SELECT account.n
    FROM account, contract
    WHERE contract.n = account.r$contract
    AND account.n = contract.n )
ORDER BY a.n
```

and

2)

```
SELECT account.n
FROM account, contract
WHERE contract.n = account.r$contract
AND account.n = contract.n
```

In 1 there are 47 rows, but in 2 - 15. I can't understand why

Comment: In the first query, you only restrict the list of accounts by the C.n clause. In the second query, you restrict the rows in account by both account.n AND account.r$contract. This must mean that there are lots of contracts that match account by just account.n, but far fewer that match on both account.n AND account.r$contract. In short, you are not filtering the first query by rows in contract that match both the `n` and the `r$contract`, just by the r$contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, I'll just try...

If query 2 returns 15 rows, then also the inner select of query 1 does, as it looks identical to me..

so query 1 is like

```
SELECT a.n
FROM account a, contract c
WHERE c.n = a.r$contract
AND c.n IN ( <any of the 15 values> )
ORDER BY a.n
```

And that is different from

```
SELECT a.n
FROM account a, contract c
WHERE c.n = a.r$contract
AND c.n = a.n              ( <-just one possible value)
ORDER BY a.n
```

So that might explain why you get different result sets.